# How can I attach a file to an email from a url?

Tags: file, email, url, coldfusion, cfmail

I'm sending an email using the `cfmail` tag, and trying to attach a PDF file from a URL:

```
<cfmail to="me@mydomain.com" from="you@yourdomain.com" subject="Subject" type="html">
   <cfmailparam file="http://myfilelocation/pdfFile.pdf">
   Body of the email
</cfmail>
```

However, this is not working. Without the `cfmailparam` tag, the email sends successfully. If I go to `http://myfilelocation/pdffile.pdf`, I see the PDF document that I'm trying to attach. Am I doing something wrong? How can I attach a PDF document to an email **from a URL**?

Comment: If you sending an HTML email, why not just link to the PDF directly?

Comment: @Paul Perigny - brilliant idea :) Don't know why we didn't think of that. Just ran the idea past my boss and it was approved :) Thanks! (If you post it as an answer I can accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are send HTML email, why not just link to the PDF directly? This makes for smaller emails and gives you a chance to update the PDF even after it is sent out.

Answer (score 2):

The `cfmailparam file` should point to a location on your server. This file is then attached to the email:

```
<cfmail to="me@mydomain.com" from="you@yourdomain.com" subject="Subject" type="html">
<cfmailparam file="d:\websites\mysite\resources\pdf1.pdf">
   Body of the email
</cfmail>
```

Comment: There's no way to do it from a url?

Comment: @froadie what problem are you trying to avoid? is the pdf on your server or somewhere else?

Comment: you can use @larzuk's answer to download the file to your own server and then follow my answer above, or simply include a link to the pdf wherever it is

Comment: that's the error. I'm including the link to wherever it is and it's not working.

Comment: @froadie no use an `<a href=` link in the body of the email, not in the `cfmailparam` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use CFHTTP to retrieve your file to your server and getTempFile() || getTempDirectory() to temporary stock this file and finally use CFMAILPARAM to attach this file.

Edit:

```
<cfset tempFile = getTempDirectory(getTempFile()) />
<cfhttp url="http://myfilelocation/pdfFile.pdf" method="get" file="#tempFile#"></cfhttp>

<cfmail to="me@mydomain.com" from="you@yourdomain.com" subject="Subject" type="html">
   <cfmailparam file="#tempFile#">
   Body of the email
</cfmail>
```

Not tested

Comment: <cfset tempFile = getTempDirectory(getTempFile()) /> should be <cfset tempFile = getTempFile(getTempDirectory(),"prefix_") />

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work fine for text files only. For other files we need conversion of data. See below:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://myfilelocation/pdfFile.pdf">
<!---conversion--->
<cfif IsSimpleValue(cfhttp.Filecontent)>
    <cfset content = cfhttp.Filecontent>
<cfelse>
    <cfset content = cfhttp.Filecontent.toByteArray()>
</cfif>
```

And cfmailparam like:

```
<cfmailparam file="#fileNameOfYourChoice#" type="#cfhttp.Mimetype#" content="#content#" />
```

This works with special URLs(eg: http://myfilelocation/pdfFile.pdf?querystring=1 or http://myfilelocation/notPdfFileName/) and also allow us to name the file as we need